# updating normal in bufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I have two cylinders which intersect on one end. I can change the radius of the intersection separately but still they meet at one end as shown below. However, I want the intersection between these two be smooth or in other words, their normals in the intersection to be shared as mentioned here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/.
I have set the normal updates TRUE, and also change all the y components of the normals to zero in the intersection. It is still not showing a smooth intersection. These two cylinders are made with BufferGeometry.[image]

so part of my code that is more important: 1- since the geometry is BufferGeometry, I use two commands below first for both geometries to create the normals:

```
comp.mesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
comp.mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

2- then since both geometries has same number of vertices, I set y component of all vertices to 0:

```
for (i=0;i<comp.mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array.length;i++){
comp.mesh.geometry.attributes.normal.array[i*3 + 1]  = 0;
comp1.mesh.geometry.attributes.normal.array[i*3 + 1]  = 0;
}
```

When I let the program show the normals, their y component of normals is 0, but the geometry is not smooth yet.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Thank you WestLangley. Please see the code in the added link.

Comment: Please share your code in your post (preferably as a snippet). If the jsfiddle is ever deleted, then the context of your question goes away with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way possible to do this is to weld these points. You need to check for duplicates, and assign them the same index. Use these indecis for triangulation and for vertex normal computation.

Comment: You technically don't need to combine the geometries as long as the normals are adjusted correctly. Here's an example where two separate meshes barely touch, yet appear smooth because I adjusted their normals. https://jsfiddle.net/TheJim01/gnoxeoem/

Comment: You explicitly set them which is fine if you know what they need to be. For a more general solution, you need to somehow tell the verts there which faces they need to average.

Comment: I updated my example to calculate them instead. Granted, mine is a very simple example. For something like what Hesamoy is trying to do, one would need to collect the normals for all vertices at a location, average them, and apply the average to all of the referenced normal locations within the buffer. One could even use the existing indices to help. Yes, one could make the buffer more efficient by removing duplicates, but it would still require doing a bunch of cross-products to get all the face normals for the vertices whose normals were just invalidated. Better to leave the indexing alone.